# My custom CSS file is not tranferred to the webpage from the server for jquery mobile

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

i'm new to JQUERY MOBILE and I'm having trouble getting my custom CSS to work.
I have read on many posts that I have to my custom css file under the jquery css file.
Well i code it that way. so it gets to the browser, but it seems that the jquery css overrides it, until I press f5. I have cleared my cache and it still seems to only respond to my pressing f5, can anyone explain what it going on here?

Here is the code as you asked me to do and the files could not be found:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/test.css"/>
```

I have also tried these two ways also and while the files could be found i have the original issue both these ways:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/test.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/test.css"/>
```

Not only that, my javascript doesn't start til i press the f5 button also.

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/test.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you try to create multiple html pages so Add your customized css and js into following structure

```
<div data-role=page>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/test.css"/>
<script src="scripts/test.js"></script>
</div>
```

Note:Add Only for your custom css and js only

Answer (score 0):

Can you copy and paste your link rel exactly as you have it in your document?

Does it look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
```

If yes then add a leading "/" at the start of the root:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
```